# EF creates InitialCreate in MigrationHistory then migration is turned on & InitialCreate has a new MigrationId causing pending migration issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have two solutions, the base solution with no migrations(which is in production, so I can not wipe the data) and now I have branched of this to set up migrations and make some model changes.

First I need to set up migrations on the branched solution (second solution) so that I can apply the model changes so I:

- Turn on migrations which auto creates an InitialMigration
  *Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Context*
- Make a blank migration based on the suggestion from  https://www.apress.com/gp/blog/all-blog-posts/secular-trends-for-the-cloud/12097630
  *Add-Migration InitialBlank -IgnoreChanges*
- Update Database * update-database*
- Make my model changes
- Add a migration containing my model changes * Add-Migration add_entity*
- Run Update-Database

So I delete the database created as I need to run the first solution to create the initial db setup (to mimic live).

When I run the first solution it creates an entry in MigrationsHistory table named InitialCreate (201807061432030_InitialCreate), which has been auto created. I then run update-database on the second solution which applies my model changes fine although their are discrepancies in the InitialCreate MigrationId.

Migration entries in my second solution (in order they were created and the order they are in the solution):
- 201807061257015_InitialCreate
- 201807061315294_InitialBlank
- 201807061323086_add_entity

Migration entries in the migration history table after running the first then second solution:

1 | 201807061315294_InitialBlank
2 | 201807061323086_add_entity
3 | 201807061432030_InitialCreate

The second solution runs fine but when I try to add any data I get *System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'Context' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database*.

I have tried to create another migration on the second project to make sure their are no model changes that have not been migrated (their shouldn't be) but I get an error. 
*Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201807061257015_InitialCreate]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.*

My questions:

1. How do I resolve the MigrationId mismatch? As the first solution did not have migrations turned on and when I do turn them on (in the second solution) it creates a new id.
2. Could the exception *System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'Context'* be thrown by the MigrationId mismatch or could anyone point me at why this could be happening? I have had a look into this error but the solution's I found don't seem to work:

   - Deleting the migrations history table is no good as I can not do this in production because of customer data.
   - The other solution I found of adding *Database.SetInitializer(null);* to global.asax seems to make no difference.
3. Why does the order of my migrations look different once they have been applied in the migration history table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be very careful with automatic migrations. They cause migraines at times and are not worth the stress. From my experience I disable auto migrations and simply run the Create Migration command when I want to. Then I can modify the contents of the migration before I apply it. Please just keep this mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work but I think I may need to manually delete the first InitialCreate and edit the db entries to reflect the correct InitialCreate. Based of this SO question I just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108243/3172635.

I will have to try this Monday though.

**Edit:** I first tried deleting the InitialMigration entry in the _MigrationHistory table but this does not work as it tries to apply the InitialMigrations again but cant as the tables are already created. So what I did was update the MigrationId for the InitialMigration entry to reflect what it was in the new project.

The sql I used:
SET MigrationId='201807061257015_InitialCreate' WHERE MigrationId = '201807061432030_InitialCreate'

Comment: I read that other answer you linked to, i have done that process before and it does work. It was during this dark period in my Migration history that I figured out it may be for the best  if I disable auto-migrations.